# C++ Windows detect killing from applications tab in Task Manager?

Tags: windows, kill-process, user32, window-managers

On Windows I get WM_CLOSE message which is handled by WndProc, which notifies application is being quit either through -

1. User clicked cross(X) button
2. User pressed Alt+F4 Keyboard shortcut
3. User right click on application icon in taskbar and clicked "Close window"/"Close all windows"
4. User went to Task Manager and from Applications tab, clicked on End Task

Before even WM_CLOSE, windows sends following message and we can use it to detect the above:

message=WM_SYSCOMMAND (WndProc) and wParam=SC_CLOSE and lParam != 0 **implies** "1." i.e. Cross(X) button

message=WM_SYSCOMMAND (WndProc) and wParam=SC_CLOSE and lParam = 0 **implies** "2.", "3." or "4."

Please note "2." can be detected by listening WM_SYSKEYDOWN and wParam = VK_F4 (received even before WM_SYSCOMMAND)

Now any idea how do I distinguish between "3." and "4." as well?

**Ultimately I need to do something when my application is killed from applications tab in Task Manager.**

Comment: call [`InSendMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-insendmessage) when you process `WM_CLOSE` in case 3 it return *false* and in case 4 (from task manager) *true*

Comment: Note that this means the the close message came via `SendMessage`, will also apply to other external ways of ending a program, such as taskkill.exe. It's not exclusively the "applications tab in Task Manager".